# Error while installing XML in R 3.3.2 on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: r, xml, gnu-make

While running makefile I got error:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'Utils.o', needed by 'XML.so'.  Stop.

I tried looking at other questions but did not understand. Can anyone please tell me what changes do I need to make in this makefile. I am going through instructions on this page:

Below are few lines from the code from the makefile .

```
S=Splus5
SHOME=/usr/local/src/Splus5.1

# Set this to be R or S
#LANGUAGE=S
LANGUAGE=R


# Set either of these as appropriate.
#LIBXML=/usr2/Downloads/libxml-1.8.6
#LIBXML=/home/duncan/XML/libxml2-2.0.0
#LIBXML=/home/duncan/XML/libxml-1.8.9

#LIBXML=/home/duncan/XML/libxml2-2.2.7
LIBXML=/home/rgentlem/XML/libxml2-2.2.11
LIBXML2=1
#LIBEXPAT=$(HOME)/XML/expat


ifndef LIBXML
ifndef LIBEXPAT
message: 
endif
```

Do I need to change the location of the LIBXML becuase I need XML in R ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. 9 random lines from a makefile
are not helpful. You need to enable readers to reproduce
the steps which led you to this problem. The link
`file:///home/ibab/Documents/softwares/XML/index.html#PackageOverview`
is a link to a file on your computer, not a webpage.

Comment: Check for the Utils.o file where is located, someone should have create that file?